# how to set the same font size as previous input on a createElement input? [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, input, font-size

I want to ***increase/decrease*** ***`font-size`*** of every input field that has been created with ***`createElement`*** with javascript.

A good example of this practice is [Word Online](https://office.live.com/start/Word.aspx).
When you increase the `font-size` of an input field, the `font-size` will stay the same on every input field. I ***haven't tried it myself*** because i dont have a single clue where to begin.

Here is my HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="nav"> </div>
    <div id="paper">
    <div id="inputcontent">
        <input type="text" class="input1">
    </div>
</div>
    <script src="src/index.js">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #333333;
}

#paper{
  background: white;
  width: 600px;
  height: 900px;
  margin-left: 500px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.input1{
  margin-top: 75px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 0px solid;
}

#inputcontent{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#nav{
  width: 1000px;
  height: 40px;
  background: darkgreen;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 350px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
import "./styles.css";

const input1 = document.querySelector('.input1');

const inputAdd = input1.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
if((e.keyCode === 13)){
  let inptPlus = document.createElement("input");
  let contentInput = document.getElementById('inputcontent');
  contentInput.appendChild(inptPlus); 
    inptPlus.style.width = "500px";
    inptPlus.style.marginLeft = "50px";
    inptPlus.style.marginTop = "1px";
    inptPlus.style.border = "0px solid";
    inptPlus.focus();
}
});
```

Comment: It's unclear exactly what your question is. You've stated what you want to do and it seems from your code that you already know how to apply styling to dynamically created elements, so what is the problem/question here?

Comment: You could do querySelectorAll and then add the listeners in a for each over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to give each created element a class.  You can dynamically add and remove CSS definitions in JavaScript.

Another option would be to write a function that manually sets all the properties on an HTML element, and call that function every time you create an element.

Another option is to make a "factory" where you create the element, set all of its properties, then return the new element.  Call that instead of the `createElement` method.

The final approach works, but I *strongly* recommend against it:  Overwrite the `createElement` method with your own factory.  I discourage it enough I won't even describe how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

After the new `input` is generated and there is text in it, click on the **A** or **a** in the top-left and see comments inline below:

```js
const input1 = document.querySelector('.input1');

// Keep this out of the event handler so you don't have to
// keep scanning for the same element over and over.
let contentInput = document.getElementById('inputcontent');
    
const inputAdd = input1.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    if((e.keyCode === 13)){
      let inptPlus = document.createElement("input");
      // Don't use inline styles if you can avoid it.
      // They make it more difficult to override later and
      // they result in a lot of code duplication. Just
      // apply/remove pre-made CSS classes instead.
      // Also, to be able to differentiate dynamically created elements
      // from static ones, give the new elements a class
      inptPlus.classList.add("dynamic");

      // Always append after configuration is complete
      contentInput.appendChild(inptPlus); 
      inptPlus.focus();
    }
});

// Handle clicks at the document level
document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  // Check to see if a font size span was clicked
  if(event.target.classList.contains("changeSize")){
  
    // Check to see which one
    let sizeChange = event.target.classList.contains("bigger") ? 1 : -1;
  
    // Loop over all dynamically created inputs
    document.querySelectorAll(".dynamic").forEach(function(input){
      // Reset the font size to the current size plust the adjustment amount
      input.style.fontSize = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(input).fontSize) + sizeChange + "px";
    });
  }
});
```

```css
*{
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      background: #333333;
    }
    /* All new controls will have this style */
    .dynamic {
      width: 500px;
      margin-left:50px;
      margin-top:1px;
      border:0 solid;
    }
    
    /* Just for the A and a at the top-left */
    .bigger, .smaller { color:#fff; font-weight:bold; font-size:1.2em; cursor:pointer; }    
    
    #paper{
      background: white;
      width: 600px;
      height: 900px;
      margin-left: 500px;
      margin-top: 50px;
    }
    
    .input1{
      margin-top: 75px;
      margin-left: 50px;
      width: 500px;
      border: 1px solid;
    }
    
    #inputcontent{
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    #nav{
      width: 1000px;
      height: 40px;
      background: darkgreen;
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      left: 350px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
     <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
     <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <span class="changeSize bigger">A</span>  <span class="changeSize smaller">a</span>
     <div id="nav"> </div>
     <div id="paper">
     <div id="inputcontent">
      <input type="text" class="input1">
     </div>
    </div>
     <script src="src/index.js"></script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```